# In which DPI resolution should I design an app in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, resolution, dpi

I am currently doing an app design. Which DPI I should start work in? I have worked on a project in 72 dpi but I want to know if this is the best size to work in.

Comment: Hi Pv Vimal Nair, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DPI is a relation of pixels to printed size. Pay attention to device pixel size, not DPI. DPI doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi casheera, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

casheera is correct. The DPI setting in photoshop is completely irrelevant to creating on-screen graphics.

All that matters is the pixel dimensions of the screens you want to support...also keeping in mind that some devices are 'retina' meaning that they use multiple real pixels to create one 'virtual' pixel.

For example, an iPhone 5 is 640 pixels wide, but uses virtual pixel dimensions of 320 pixels.

So if you create a PSD file for that particular device, you'd set the width of your file to 640, but you'd treat things like type as being on a 320 pixel screen. To do that, you'd double the real pixel dimensions. For example, 12px type in your PSD file should be set as 24px.